# how to compare and merge two list according to its sequence in python?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, numpy

Let say i have two lists that is intended to be merged:

```
a=[0.1,0.2,'-','-',0.3]
b=['-','-',0.4,0.5,'-']
```

how to merge a and b to its current position to be like this?

```
c=[0.1,0.2,0.4,0.5,0.3]
```

thanks

Comment: What have you tried (show code as properly formatted text in the question)?

Comment: Are you using python lists, pandas series or numpy arrays? Do you always have one `'-'` per position in either or the other list?

Comment: @mozway it is actually a dataframe, and i have filtered out None values and NaN values to '-'

Comment: @AfiqKhairuddin it would be much better to leave those values as NaN ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming either a or b has a float for a given position.

One possibility:

```
c = [x if isinstance(x, float) else y for x,y in zip(a,b)]
```

output: `[0.1, 0.2, 0.4, 0.5, 0.3]`

Using [pandas](/questions/tagged/pandas):

```
pd.Series(a).replace('-', pd.NA).fillna(pd.Series(b))
```

output:

```
0    0.1
1    0.2
2    0.4
3    0.5
4    0.3
dtype: float64
```